# Regex - cant get HTML table rows from string created from file, but works from string in code

Tags: html, regex, parsing

I am trying to extract all the table rows from an html file.  I read the HTML file into a string and then parse it.  When I parse that string, it never finds any table rows, but when I use the exact same regular expression to find it from a string that has the same contents as the file, it works.

I have attached the playground that illustrates the problem.  I dont get why it works on my hardcoded string (that I copied from the file) but won't from the string created from reading the file.

Note: The contents of the file are exactly the same as the string i use in code.I will attach the entire playground file if someone can tell me how to attach a file to the question

Any ideas?

```
import Foundation

 extension String
{
    func captureGroups(withRegex pattern: String, withStartPos startPos: inout Int) -> [String]
    {
        var results = [String]()

        var regex: NSRegularExpression

        // NSRegularExpression throws exception if error so I need to trap that
        do {
            regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            return results
        }

        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [],
                                    range: NSRange(location:startPos, length: self.characters.count-startPos))

        // Reset the string position to be the end od the currently matched expression
        // This allows me to find the next thing in the string from where I left off
        if let posFound = matches.first?.range.location
        {
            startPos = posFound + matches.first!.range.length   // Start at end of last
        }

        guard let match = matches.first
        else { return results }

        let lastRangeIndex = match.numberOfRanges - 1
        guard lastRangeIndex >= 1
        else { return results }

        for i in 1...lastRangeIndex {
            let capturedGroupIndex = match.rangeAt(i)
            let matchedString = (self as NSString).substring(with: capturedGroupIndex)
            results.append(matchedString)
        }

        return results
    }
} // extenstion String

var contents = ""
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testTR", ofType: "html")!

do {
    contents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
    print("CONTENTS: \(contents)")
}
catch {
    print("file not found")
}

var myStartPos: Int = 0
var foundMatch: [String]

foundMatch = contents.captureGroups(withRegex: "<tr>(.*)</tr>", withStartPos: &myStartPos)
if foundMatch.isEmpty{
    print("Didnt find any rows ???")
}

myStartPos = 0
foundMatch = "<tr><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>1.2 mi</strong></td><td><strong>22:12</strong></td><td><strong>22:12</strong></td><td><strong>1:08/100m</strong></td><td><strong>1</strong></td><td><strong>2</strong></td><td><strong>4</strong></td></tr>".captureGroups(withRegex: "<tr>(.*)</tr>", withStartPos: &myStartPos)
```

Here is contents of the file I am using:

```
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td><strong>1.2 mi</strong></td>
          <td><strong>22:12</strong></td>
            <td><strong>22:12</strong></td>
            <td><strong>1:08/100m</strong></td>
          <td><strong>1</strong></td>
          <td><strong>2</strong></td>
          <td><strong>4</strong></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Please tag thecquestion with the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
<tr>((.|\n)*)</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>((.|\n|\r)*)</tr>
```

'.' matches only one-line character

Comment: Thanks.  That works, but I still don't get why .* didn't work since it should match any character.

Comment: Also, it sill does not seem to match correct </tr> at the end -- it just matches to the very last </tr> or the end of the file.  all the other </tr> tags get put inside the first match so it does not get the first (or any) ending </tr>

Comment: Use non-greedly: <tr>((.|\n)*?)</tr>

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the help gang.  Guess I better spend some more time training myself on regular expressions.